# Morse Knocking by monitoring connection duration

Tags: c, iptables, knockd

Recently learned about the concept of [Port Knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking). Instead of opening ports, could tracking the duration of opening and closing a client connection be used? For example, to send SOS (...---...)

- Open 3 connections for 100ms: ...
- Open 3 connections for 300ms: ---
- Open 3 connections for 100ms: ...

**MSVC example**

```
// Morse Knocking - Connection Duration: 100ms = dot, 300ms = dash.

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#define dot 100
#define dash 300

int __cdecl main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SOCKET client_socket;
    const int SIZE = 3;

    // Morse code distress signal ...---...
    char morse[SIZE] = { 'S', 'O', 'S'};

    WSADATA wsaData;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        switch (morse[i])
        {
        case 'S':
            for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
            {
                client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof server);
                Sleep(dot);
                closesocket(client_socket);               
            }
        case 'O':
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof server);
                Sleep(dash);
                closesocket(client_socket);
            }
        default:
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're asking if this is possible? Sure, as long as the firewall supports it.

Comment: Just don't be surprised that Windows is not a real-time system, it will insert delays. And trying this between remote computers can have a lot of jitter.